# Spring security always returning 403

Tags: spring, spring-security

Can someone tell me why this code is always returning 403?

I mapped /login to trigger the security login but it is not working properly.

```
package esercizio.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("q@q").password("pluto").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login.jsp")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/auth/list-student")
        .failureUrl("/errorPage")
        .and()
        .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.jsp");
    }
}
```

It should let anyone in if the URL doesn't start with /auth, I don't know why it doesn't happen.

Comment: @dur i already have csrf configurated in my form

Answer (score -1):

I think, you must prepend 'ROLE_' to you authority like ROLE_USER.

For more visit :

[Spring Security always return the 403 accessDeniedPage after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180028/spring-security-always-return-the-403-accessdeniedpage-after-login?rq=1)

Comment: It is added automatically by spring